# PHP and Pug (phug) Project Structure

Tags: php, pug

I am starting a new project in PHP and would like to leverage Pug for this new project. I would usually structure my php project simply as:

```
project
 |- css
 |- src
 | |- library (.php files interacting with the backend, no UI code)
 | |- views (.php files containing HTML)
 | |- index.php (home page re-using views to create the web-app)
```

I am now trying to use Pug and decided on using [pug-php/pug](https://phug-lang.com/). But I cannot figure out the high-level structure. How would I re-write the above structure if I were using Pug?

Comment: Why do you want to use pugjs? Out of interest

Comment: well, personally, just for the ease of writing html (the templates are much cleaner, easier, faster to write with pug). Are there alternatives that work better with php?